# How to connect to JDBC database from within Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

From *within* Oracle RDBMS I would like to connect and query/manipulate data in a remote JDBC compliant database.

Ideally I would like to use the remote JDBC database through an Oracle database link. I was hoping that I would be able to do it just like for any other database link:

```sql
UPDATE table1@remoteJDBClink
SET col1  = 'Joe';
```

It seems to me that Oracle database links are limited to where Oracle has created a Gateway product for the target db. They do support "Generic ODBC" as a target, but strangely I cannot figure out how I would do "Generic JDBC" as the target db.

Any other suggestions as to how I would query/manipulate a remote JDBC database from within Oracle are more than welcome. Perhaps the whole Gateway stuff in Oracle has been superseded by something else that I should use?  At least I feel the [information about the topic on Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/gateways/index.html) seem a bit dated.

My requirements are very simple: Just basic SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT. No cross-database joins, no distributed transactions, etc. I wonder if Oracle allows one to build my own Gateway?

Oracle version: 11g (or better)

Comment: You could create stored procedures in Java which then use JDBC to connect to the other DBMS.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't think of that. It wouldn't be as transparent/generic as the DB Link method, would it?

Comment: You are right. It wouldn't be transparent at all.